# How can I remove first name from surname when the length is unknown?

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, cut

I'm trying to write a simple bash script in which the user inputs their username, then they are greeted, depending on the time of day by their surname. I currently have the following:

```
echo Please enter your username
read username
name=$(grep $username /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 5)

h='date +%H'

if [ $h -lt 12]; then
  echo Good morning ${name::-3)
```

etc. etc.

I have managed to cut the 3 commas off the end of the name that are there, but I want to be able to cut the first name off.

For example:

- The `$name` is `Amber Martin,,,`.
- I've cut down to `Amber Martin`.
- I need to cut down further to `Martin`.
- And this needs to work with any name.

Comment: Did you mean `h=$(date +%H)` rather than `h='date +%H'`?

Comment: I'm guessing this is just for an exercise or a personal thing, since parsing names and getting everything correct for every edge case is basically impossible. See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You don't. Guessing names is incredibly complicated. For example, here are some people all of whose last name is "Smith": John Smith, J. W. Smith, John William Smith, John-Jack Smith, John William Watson Smith. Basically, there are so many different naming conventions in different places and cultures that doing this 100% correctly is exceedingly hard.

Comment: Plus, even if you decide that surname == last name, you need to decide what happens if Cher or Madonna sign up.

Comment: ah the old, Juan Pablo Fernández de Calderón García-Iglesias problem

Answer (score 11):

Better to use `getent passwd` than to read `/etc/passwd` directly. `getent` also works with LDAP, NIS and such. I think it exists in most Unixes. (My OS X doesn't have it, but it doesn't have my account in `/etc/passwd` either, so...)

```sh
name=$(getent -- passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5)
```

The string processing can be done with the shell's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), these are POSIX compatible:

```sh
name=${name%%,*}         # remove anything after the first comma
name=${name%,,,}         # or remove just a literal trailing ",,,"
name=${name##* }         # remove from start until the last space
echo "hello $name"
```

Use `${name#* }` to remove until the first space. (Just hope no-one has a two-part last name, with space in between).

The `cut` could also be replaced with word-splitting or `read`, by setting `IFS` to a colon.

Comment: This will only work if the unwanted part is literally `,,,` (i.e. no location or phone information).  It would be more robust to cut everything from the first comma: `name=${name%%,*}`.

Comment: Is this compatible with every *nix? Or only linux?

Comment: @TobySpeight, ah, yes, that's true. (Hopefully no-one's name contains a comma)

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini, the prefix and suffix -removing string operations are from POSIX, I think getent is common.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
#And also /bin/sh looks like to be compatible in debian.  
echo "Hmmm... Your username looks like to be $USER"
name="$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1)"
echo "Your full name is $name"
surname="$(echo $name | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev)"
echo "Your surname is $surname"
echo "thank your for using only cut and rev to do that..."
echo "But i am sure there is a better way"
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the [GECOS (comment) field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field), you can simply perform another `cut` to remove the (empty in your case) location and phone number fields, this time with `,` as the separator:

```sh
name=$(getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1)
echo "Hello, ${name##* }-san!"
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to deal with [all the different possibilities](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) of what is a "surname"!

Comment: Upvoted for the "falsehoods" link. :)